# paintcomponent not called by constructor or when object is created

Tags: java

I have 2 classes: GameOfLife() and PanelGrid. When a new object of panelgrid is created, the (overwritten) method paintComponent is not called. Putting "repaint()" in the constructor doesn't work either.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

class GameOfLife {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game of life");
    PanelGrid panelGrid;

    void buildIt() {
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(buttonStart, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(buttonStop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panelGrid = new PanelGrid();
        panelGrid.setOpaque(true);
        frame.add(panelGrid);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameOfLife().buildIt();
    }
}

class PanelGrid extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    Timer timer;
    int delay;
    JLabel label;
    int height; // get length from the file
    int width; //get width of array from the file

    //constructor
    public PanelGrid() {
        delay = 1000;
        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
        width = 4;
        height = 5;
        //if there exists a file with an initial configuration, initial[][], width and height are updated.
        //if not, the default array is used
        readInitial();
        //repaint();  putting repaint() here din't make a difference.
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("if you read this, the method is called");
    super.paintComponent(g); //erases panel content
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(width, height));
    for (int r = 0; r < height; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < width; c++) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            if (grid[r][c].isAlive() == true) {
                panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            } else {                    
                panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
            this.add(panel);
        }
    }
    //the rest of this class I have left out for clarity
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile.  The action listener in the PanelGrid class is missing.  The grid is not defined.  You do not define Swing components in the paintComponent method.  Take a look at my [John Conway’s Game of Life in Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=504) article and see if it provides you with any hints.

Comment: How about setting `frame.setVisible(true);` as the last statement in your constructor?

Comment: Also... `JPanel panel = new JPanel();` and `this.add(panel);` in your `paintComponent` implementation? That's a big NO-NO. Paint component is *only* for painting, not for building/adding components or laying them out. Strictly painting. You must rethink your strategy. Also, if you want help from us, it might help to explain in more detail what it is you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add your PanelGrid to the`JFrame`. If it's not in a visible top-level container `paint()` and therefore `paintComponent()` won't be called. Maybe. Worth a shot...

Comment: Sorry, ment that as a comment not an answer (as I've no idea if it'll work)